# Cross Thread Exception with Throttle in Reactive Extensions

Tags: silverlight, exception, system.reactive

I am using Reactive Extensions to verification of a textbox input.
I am trying to use the .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).

But when I add the .Throttle() method a cross thread exception is thrown when accessing a UI object in the .Subscribe() method.

It works 100% without the Throttle, why is it breaking?

My code:

```
 var textChangedEvent = Observable.FromEvent<TextChangedEventArgs>(usernameTextbox, "TextChanged")
                                    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))

        textChangedEvent.Subscribe(changed =>
            {
                TextBox oUsernameTextBox = changed.Sender as TextBox;

                //Accessing oUsernameTextBox throws Cross Thread Exception
            });
```

Thanks
-Oliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `Throttle` uses the `ThreadpoolScheduler` so events will not arrive on the UI Thread.  Since you need the events on the UI thread use:-

```
var textChangedEvent = Observable.FromEvent<TextChangedEventArgs>(usernameTextbox, "TextChanged")
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), Scheduler.Dispatcher);
```

This will put the events back on the UI Thread.

Comment: +1 Any operator that has an `IScheduler` overload cannot be trusted to run on the same thread as the caller. It's also preferable to use the `IScheduler` overload rather than using `ObserveOn`

Comment: Actually I believe it defaults to the `ThreadPoolScheduler` in .NET 4

Comment: brilliant, just started with RX. Thanks guys. @Richard, thanks for the advice on IScheduler... I will look out for it now.

Comment: BTW: It was Scheduler.Dispatcher in SL4 for anyone else looking at this.

Comment: @Oliver:  You're right, I was reading the type not the property name; answer edited.

Comment: System.Reactive.Concurrency.DispatcherScheduler.Instance in v1.0.1061+

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak the code a bit to make it work in a LightSwitch (SilverLight 4) application with Rx v1.0.10621 due to some interface changes in Rx since when this question had been asked.

Need to [install Rx](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28568) and to reference `System.Reactive` and `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading` assemblies (for LightSwitch this reference go in the `Client` project).

Then use this code to throttle a the `TextChange` event on the text box:

*(Note: For lightswitch this code goes in the `ControlAvailable` handler)*

```
var textChangedEvent = Observable
                       .FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(e.Control, "TextChanged")
                       .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                       .ObserveOnDispatcher();

        textChangedEvent.Subscribe(changed =>
        {
            var tb = changed.Sender as TextBox;
            if (tb.Text.Length >= 3) // don't search for keywords shorter than 3 chars
            {
                // search
            }
        });
```